# Nokogiri - Returning a Filtered Array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is it possible to just return the actual image source links, rather than the entire nokogiri array object?

```
def self.images(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  images = doc.css('img[src$="jpg"], img[src$="png"]').select do |image|
    image['src'] =~ %r{^http://(\d+|media)}
  end
  images
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map) to convert the array of elements to an array containing all the `src` attributes.

```
def self.images(url)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css('img[src$="jpg"], img[src$="png"]').select do |image|
    image['src'] =~ %r{^http://(\d+|media)}
  end.map { |i| i['src'] }
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, thanks! That might just be the only I can do this.